# How to calculate RANK based on Dates using DAX in a Matrix, when one column is coming from another table and DATE column is Dates table

Tags: powerbi, rank

I need to create a calculated column in a Matrix table, To flag a value when the First value is Cashflow column is negative, For Example in the screenshot A company 'Alliance' can have multiple cashflows in the last few years I need to check based on dates if the first cashflow for this company was negative.

For this, I planned to use the Rank function to first assign a rank for the very first cash flow based on the minimum date grouped by each company. And company name is coming from a different table and the date is in a different table and there is a relation in the data model. How to assign a rank for the dates grouped by a Company name which is in a different table, how to get column D as in the screenshot? This needs to be done in PowerBI using DAX but I have attached sample data in Excel.
[image: [Sample data in Excel, expected values in column D in powerBI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a1WPo.png)]